# Calling vuex store within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

I would like to refresh my access tokens just before they expire. My API responds with a property to define when the access token expires. For testing purposes, this is set to 2 minutes.

Since I know when the access token is due to expire, I prefer to handle this before the user gets a `401` so when the user logs in, a `setTimeout` is set like so:

```
async login(userName: string, password: string): Promise<Token> {
  const request: AccountLogin = {
    userName,
    password,
  };
  const result = await this.axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/auth/login`, request);
  const token = this.jsonConvert.deserializeObject(result.data, Token);
  getModule(TokenModule, this.store).setToken(token);
  setTimeout(this.tokenService.refresh, token.expires * 1000, this);
  return token;
}
```

The `setTimeout` eventually calls this method:

```
async refresh(): Promise<void> {
  debugger;
  console.log('refreshed');
  let token = getModule(TokenModule, this.store).token!;
  const request: RefreshTokenRequest = {
    refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
  };
  const result = await this.axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/token/refresh`, request);
  token = this.jsonConvert.deserializeObject(result.data, Token);
  getModule(TokenModule, this.store).setToken(token);
}
```

The `debugger` line is hit and a log appears in the console. However when it tries to retrieve the token from the store I get this error:

```
Error: ERR_STORE_NOT_PROVIDED: To use getModule(), either the module
            should be decorated with store in decorator, i.e. @Module({store: store}) or
            store should be passed when calling getModule(), i.e. getModule(MyModule, this.$store)
```

Without the `setTimeout` this piece of functionality works. This is my store:

```
@Module({ name: 'tokenModule' })
export class TokenModule extends VuexModule {
  token: Token | null = null;

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  @Mutation
  setToken(token: Token) {
    this.token = token;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am not a huge fan of async syntax but did you try to do:  setTimeout(() => {this.tokenService.refresh();}, token.expires * 1000);

Comment: from the error description, it seems the context issue. what is `this.store` in this line `let token = getModule(TokenModule, this.store).token!;`?

Comment: @user3791775 That doesn't even call the `refresh` method

Comment: @Sphinx The `store` is dependency injected `store: Store<any>`

Comment: so you already checked the value of `this.store` is correct?

Comment: @KTOV If the setTimeout does not work I giive up...it should (the arrow function should take care of the context). What if you do setTimeout(() => {this.tokenService.refresh();}, 10 * 1000); (hardcoded 10 seconds)

Comment: @Sphinx Without the timeout the value of `this.store` is correct but with the `setTimeout` the `store` is undefined

Comment: @user3791775 That actually works! Weirdly didn't work before even though `token.expires` was 60